# Neural Network error is constant

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I am building a Recurrent Neural Network based on the one at this link: [intro to RNN in Tensorflow](http://danijar.com/introduction-to-recurrent-networks-in-tensorflow/)
But when I try to run it, the accuracy is stuck at 19.1% for the test set and similar values for the train and validation set.

From my understanding, it looks like the network is not updating the weights and biases at all, but I can't understand why.

This is the code that I am running:

```
def lazy_property(function):
    attribute = '_' + function.__name__

    @property
    @functools.wraps(function)
    def wrapper(self):
        if not hasattr(self, attribute):
            setattr(self, attribute, function(self))
        return getattr(self, attribute)
    return wrapper


class SequenceClassification:

    def __init__(self, data, target, dropout, num_hidden=200, num_layers=3):
        self.data = data
        self.target = target
        self.dropout = dropout
        self._num_hidden = num_hidden
        self._num_layers = num_layers
        self.prediction
        self.error
        self.optimize

    @lazy_property
    def prediction(self):
        # Recurrent network.
        cells = []
        for _ in range(self._num_layers):
            cell = tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(self._num_hidden) # Or LSTMCell(num_units)
            cell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(
            cell, output_keep_prob=1.0 - self.dropout)
            cells.append(cell)
        network = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(cells)
        output, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(network, self.data, dtype=tf.float32)
        # Select last output.
        output = tf.transpose(output, [1, 0, 2])
        last = tf.gather(output, int(output.get_shape()[0]) - 1)
        # Softmax layer.
        weight, bias = self._weight_and_bias(
            self._num_hidden, int(self.target.get_shape()[1]))
        prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(last, weight) + bias)
        return prediction

    @lazy_property
    def cost(self):
        cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(self.target * tf.log(self.prediction))
        return cross_entropy

    @lazy_property
    def optimize(self):
        learning_rate = 0.003
        optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate)
        return optimizer.minimize(self.cost)

    @lazy_property
    def error(self):
        mistakes = tf.not_equal(
            tf.argmax(self.target, 1), tf.argmax(self.prediction, 1))
        return tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(mistakes, tf.float32))

    @staticmethod
    def _weight_and_bias(in_size, out_size):
        weight = tf.truncated_normal([in_size, out_size], stddev=0.01)
        bias = tf.constant(0.1, shape=[out_size])
        return tf.Variable(weight), tf.Variable(bias)

batch_size = 5000
epochs = 20


def main():
    length = 5
    features_size = 55
    num_classes = 2
    data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, length, features_size])
    target = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, num_classes])
    dropout = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    model = SequenceClassification(data, target, dropout)
    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    graph = []
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        epoch_loss = 0
        i = 0
        if epoch % 3 == 0:
            random_x = np.random.permutation(train_x)
            random_y = np.random.permutation(train_y)
        # while i < len(train_x):
        while i < 100000:
            start = i
            end = i + batch_size
            batch_x = random_x[start:end]
            batch_y = random_y[start:end]
            # batch_x = train_x[start:end]
            # batch_y = train_y[start:end]
            sess.run(model.optimize, {data: batch_x, target: batch_y, dropout: 0.5})
            i += batch_size
        print('epoch {} completed'.format(epoch + 1))
        if epoch % 5 == 0:
            train_errors = []
            while i < len(train_x):
                start = i
                end = i + 100000
                batch_train_x = train_x[start:end]
                batch_train_y = train_y[start:end]
                train_errors.append(sess.run(model.error, {data: batch_train_x, target: batch_train_y, dropout: 1}))
                i += 100000
            train_error = np.mean(train_errors)
            test_error = sess.run(model.error, {data: test_x, target: test_y, dropout: 1})
            validation_error = sess.run(model.error,
                                        {data: validation_x, target: validation_y, dropout: 1})
            print('Epoch {:2d} error {:3.1f}%, loss:'.format(epoch + 1, 100 * test_error), epoch_loss)
            print([epoch + 1, train_error, test_error, None, validation_error])
            graph.append([epoch + 1, train_error, test_error, None, validation_error])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('initialising model...')
    main()
```

It is a modification of the one available at this link (which, when I tried it, had the exact same issue): [RNN sequence clasification](https://gist.github.com/danijar/c7ec9a30052127c7a1ad169eeb83f159). This is the output that I get when I run my code:

```
epoch 0 completed
Epoch  1 error 19.1%, loss: 0
[1, 0.19120942, 0.19113493, None, 0.18927938]
epoch 1 completed
epoch 2 completed
epoch 3 completed
epoch 4 completed
epoch 5 completed
Epoch  6 error 19.1%, loss: 0
[6, 0.19120942, 0.19113493, None, 0.18927938]
epoch 6 completed
epoch 7 completed
epoch 8 completed
epoch 9 completed
epoch 10 completed
Epoch 11 error 19.1%, loss: 0
[11, 0.19120942, 0.19113493, None, 0.18927938]
epoch 11 completed
epoch 12 completed
epoch 13 completed
epoch 14 completed
epoch 15 completed
Epoch 16 error 19.1%, loss: 0
[16, 0.19120942, 0.19113493, None, 0.18927938]
epoch 16 completed
epoch 17 completed
epoch 18 completed
epoch 19 completed
```

What is the cause of this issue?

Comment: Use tensorboard and visualize your graph. Check if all the layers are connected as expected.